# Print data into table using localstorage in jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, local-storage

Data is printing in my table, but two issues are found.

Note: In localStorage Data saved in correct format, and as per requirement.issues are getting while printing data from localStorage to table.

1.I am using a variable for pritning data into table from localstorage, but when I click 'add' it will again print previous array with new row, like if I have 10 rows in localstorage and if I click add it will just add new row instead of that its adding 10 previous and 1 new total 11 rows.

2.I am using localstorage because, if page is refreshed the data will still show in table, but when I refreshed data not showing on table, however its stored in localstorage, that's means I am not using correct method to getItem from localstorage

Here is my script:

```
var productData = [];

var productData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));

require(['jquery'],function(){
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var data = '';
     jQuery("#addbutton").click(function(){
        var sku = jQuery('#get_product').val();
        var getQuantity = jQuery("input[name='qty']").val();
         jQuery('.configurable').each(function () {
             sku+='-'+jQuery(this).val()
         });
        var productData2 = [];
            productData2.push({'qty': getQuantity,  'name': data.pr.name, 'sku': sku});
            if(productData == null){
                localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(productData2));
                productData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
            }else{
                productData = productData.concat(productData2);
                localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(productData));
            }
            var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
            jQuery.each(result,function (key, value) {
            jQuery("#tabledata").append('<tr><td>' + value.name + '</td><td>' + value.sku + '</td><td>' + value.qty + '</td></tr>');
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: You have written the initial display of items from local storage inside click function. Just add the push logic in click method and keep the other logic in another method and call it in JQuery.ready

Comment: @AbhisekMishra ok, data is remain into table. I remove print logic from click function, but now when I click on add, its just push data into array, not print into table, so table is not changed until page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

For Answers, Please check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nowsathns/js6gL2mv/4/)

1. Table is not cleared so it is appending the data in the list
2. Local Storage working as expected.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#addButton").click(function() {
    var productData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"));
    var productData2 = [];
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    productData2.push({
      'qty':  i,
      'name': 'name ' + i,
      'sku': 'sku ' + i
    });
    if (productData) {
      productData = productData.concat(productData2);
    } else {
      productData = productData2;
    }

    localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(productData));
    DisplayTable();
  });
});

function DisplayTable() {
  jQuery("#tabledata").html(""); //Clear the existing data
  var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products"))
  jQuery.each(result, function(key, value) {
    jQuery("#tabledata").append('<tr><td>' + value.name + '</td><td>' + value.sku + '</td><td>' + value.qty + '</td></tr>');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addButton">Add Button</button>
<br/>
<table id="tabledata">
</table>
```

Comment: can you please edit your answer, so I can see the code in better way

Comment: Please check the link https://jsfiddle.net/nowsathns/js6gL2mv/4/

Comment: if I refresh the page, data disappeared from the table